# Add extra stop words elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, stop-words

**Purpose**

remove stopword from appearing in term facets

**Environment & setup**

Mac OSX,
  ES 0.90.7  installed via homebrew

**Steps**

update config

```
# /usr/local/Cellar/elasticsearch/0.90.7/config/elasticsearch.yml
# add more Stopwords to default standard analyzer
index:
analysis:
  analyzer:
    standard:
      type: standard
      stopwords: [http, t.co]
```

restart ES

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/_analyze?analyzer=standard&pretty' -d 'this is a test http'
```

result is

```
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "test",
      "start_offset": 10,
      "end_offset": 14,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 4
    },
    {
      "token": "http",
      "start_offset": 15,
      "end_offset": 19,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 5
    }
  ]
}
```

**Expectation**

http shouldn't not be indexed nor appear in token

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to mess with analyzer configuration to exclude words from a terms facet.  You can give the `exclude` param a list of words to exclude when requesting a terms facet:

```
"facets" : {
    "body" : {
        "terms" : {
            "field" : "body",
            "exclude" : ["http". "t.co"]
        }
    }
}
```

See the [terms facet documentation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-facets-terms-facet.html) for more information.